# cant quit macports installation

Tags: macos, macports

I've tried to install macports, but it stucks at "running package scripts" for a **night**. how to close it for I will be able simply restart my mac? because each time i'm trying to restart it says "your computer can't be restarted now, because software is being installed." why? I've already force quited the installation

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this, after upgrading to Sierra and installing the Sierra version of Macports.

I checked which macports processing were running (ps ax | grep -i macports), and if theyt used much bandwidth (ie. downloading stuff, sudo nettop). It seemed to really not do much. It also seemed not to be working on rebuilding a database (as mentioned in https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1922), as that would take a lot of CPU and top/htop did not list anything that took a lot of CPU.

So i killed the processes and started macports, which started just fine so i was able to continue (saving existing ports to file, removing all, reinstall).